# How to store pointers of vectors, containing different types

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++14

I am currently learning more about the ECS pattern and have been attempting to create my own implementation as practice. I decided I want to make it more cache friendly when looping through the components by packing all my different components into vectors, instead of having a vector of pointers.

[A reference I've been reading](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/data-locality.html) suggests to put each different component type into a different array and to loop over it, like so:

```
AIComponent aiComponents[MAX_NUM];
PhysicsComponent physicsComponents[MAX_NUM];
RenderComponent renderComponents[MAX_NUM];

while (!gameOver)
{
  // Process AI.
  for (int i = 0; i < numEntities; i++)
  {
    aiComponents[i].update();
  }

  // Update physics.
  for (int i = 0; i < numEntities; i++)
  {
    physicsComponents[i].update();
  }

  // Draw to screen.
  for (int i = 0; i < numEntities; i++)
  {
    renderComponents[i].render();
  }

  // Other game loop machinery for timing...
}
```

I find this very limiting as it will require that everytime I create a new component that I will have to hand-create the array and the array loop.

I would much prefer a single field like so:

```
// A vector of pointers to other vectors of different types.
// For example, componentPool[0] could be RenderComponent and then
// componentPool[1] could be PhysicsComponent

vector< vector<AnyConcreteComponentType>* > componentPool;

for (int i = 0; i < componentPool.size(); i++)
{
    for (auto& component : componentPool[i]) {
        Update(component);
    }
}
```

This would allow me to keep adding new systems dynamically in my init(), like so:

```
AddComponent(entityId, RenderComponent());
```

Which will automatically expand the componentPool to add a new RenderComponent slot, which will then point to the newly created vector and which I could then iterate over efficiently.

Problem is that I don't know how you would do this, or even do it optimally. I'd imagine there would have to be templates, casting and a way to know, before accessing the vector, what type I require but other than that I have no clue.

Comment: Keep reading the same C++ book you're reading now. At some point, you will learn enough about inheritance and subclassing that you can figure this out on your own. This is a broad subject, that cannot be fully covered in a brief answer on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I can't use polymorphism here as I would then have to have a vector of pointers which defeats the purpose of trying to be cache friendly.

Comment: The question did not mention this kind of an exotic environment where every femtosecond is worth $$$. In that case you will need to build a completely custom container that meets your requirements. That's still going to be covered by your C++ book, but in a much later, advanced chapter; and definitely cannot be squeezed into a generic answer on stack overflow.com. A standard C++ library container will not meet your requirements.

Comment: Well, like I said this is just a learning exercise for me. I don't mind looking into creating my own container I would appreciate a hint on how it would work, to do as I described.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that you're looking for something that's hand-tailored to your particular situation, classes, and application. It's simply not possible to give any kind of a meaningful hint or a tip, other than to study how C++ classes and inheritance works. With full understanding of how things work, you should be able to figure out what implementation best fits your needs.

Comment: First question: exactly how many component types are we talking about?  1 declaration, and one loop (which can be rewritten as a "handle X" helper function and lambda) is not much boilerplate.  And how often do you really want to dynamically change the number of types of components?  That seems like a relatively silly requirement.  And dynamic typing *has costs*, if you care about speed adding "oh and make it dynamic" for no reason is very questionable.

Comment: To be ckear, I can do this 3 ways from sunday.  But I have no idea what way would be best, as that relies on an actual clear reason to do it.  A map from type id to `{any, insert func ptr, visit func ptr}`, where the any stores a vector of instances that match the type id, would be one random solution, and the types descend from a common base.  Or an abstract container of visitables.  Or type erasing iterators that know stride length and base on a raw buffer.  Or a myriad of other choices.

Comment: Did you have a look at boost variant?

Comment: I was hoping to test this with lots of different types of components. Really, the ultimate goal of this is to prevent having to manually declare the vector, for each new component, and then create a new loop for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- your question is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166663) and you only think storing pointers to vectors of different types might be *a* solution rather than *the* solution, and
- you know the list of component types at compile-time (as opposed to allowing runtime-registration),

then this is relatively easily achieved by way of a tuple and some mechanism to iterate over it.

First, we want a metafunction to produce the correct tuple type given a list of component types:

```
namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t N, typename... Components>
    std::tuple<std::array<Components, N>...>
    makeComponentPool(std::tuple<Components...>) noexcept;
} // namespace detail

template<std::size_t N, typename ComponentTup>
using ComponentPool = decltype(detail::makeComponentPool<N>(std::declval<ComponentTup>()));

// example:
static_assert(std::is_same<
    ComponentPool<10, std::tuple<AIComponent, PhysicsComponent, RenderComponent>>,
    std::tuple<
        std::array<AIComponent, 10>,
        std::array<PhysicsComponent, 10>,
        std::array<RenderComponent, 10>
    >
>::value);
```

Then we need some way of iterating over the tuple; [`boost::fusion::for_each`](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html) works well here, or we can roll our own:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename TupT, typename FunT, std::size_t... Is>
    void for_each(TupT&& tup, FunT&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        using expand = int[];
        (void)expand{0, (f(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupT>(tup))), void(), 0)...};
    }
} // namespace detail

template<
    typename TupT, typename FunT,
    std::size_t TupSize = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupT>>::value
>
void for_each(TupT&& tup, FunT&& f) {
    detail::for_each(
        std::forward<TupT>(tup), std::forward<FunT>(f),
        std::make_index_sequence<TupSize>{}
    );
}
```

Now we need to make a decision: should each component type have the same public access point? In the question there are both `update()` and `render()`; however if we can give these all the same name (e.g. `process()`) then things are quite straightforward:

```
struct AIComponent      { void process() { } };
struct PhysicsComponent { void process() { } };
struct RenderComponent  { void process() { } };

class Game {
    using ComponentTypes = std::tuple<AIComponent, PhysicsComponent, RenderComponent>;
    static constexpr std::size_t MAX_NUM = 3;

    ComponentPool<MAX_NUM, ComponentTypes> componentPool;
    std::atomic_bool gameOver{false};

public:
    void runGame() {
        while (!gameOver) {
            for_each(componentPool, [](auto& components) {
                for (auto& component : components) {
                    component.process();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    void endGame() { gameOver = true; }
};
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/987e4edc1cc35f03)**</kbd>
<sub>(N.b. in the demo `process()` was given a parameter only for exposition, not due to any implementation requirement.)</sub>

Now you just need to manage `MAX_NUM` and `ComponentTypes` and everything else falls into place.

However, if you want to allow for different access points for different component types (e.g. `update()` for `AIComponent` and `PhysicsComponent` but `render()` for `RenderComponent`, as in the question) then we obviously have a bit of work left to do. One approach is to add a level of indirection for invoking the access point, and one way to accomplish that cleanly and with minimal overhead (both syntactic and runtime) is to use some utility to create local overload sets so that component processing can be trivially special-cased by type. Here is a basic implementation that works for all functors (inc. lambdas) but not for function pointers:

```
template<typename FunT, typename... FunTs>
struct overloaded : private FunT, private overloaded<FunTs...> {
    overloaded() = default;
    template<typename FunU, typename... FunUs>
    overloaded(FunU&& f, FunUs&&... fs)
      : FunT(std::forward<FunU>(f)),
        overloaded<FunTs...>(std::forward<FunUs>(fs)...)
    { }

    using FunT::operator();
    using overloaded<FunTs...>::operator();
};

template<typename FunT>
struct overloaded<FunT> : private FunT {
    overloaded() = default;
    template<typename FunU>
    overloaded(FunU&& f) : FunT(std::forward<FunU>(f)) { }

    using FunT::operator();
};

template<typename... FunTs>
overloaded<std::decay_t<FunTs>...> overload(FunTs&&... fs) {
    return {std::forward<FunTs>(fs)...};
}
```

If needed, more robust implementations of `overload` can be found online, but even with this simple implementation we can now do the following:

```
struct AIComponent      { void update() { } };
struct PhysicsComponent { void update() { } };
struct RenderComponent  { void render() { } };

class Game {
    using ComponentTypes = std::tuple<AIComponent, PhysicsComponent, RenderComponent>;
    static constexpr std::size_t MAX_NUM = 3;

    ComponentPool<MAX_NUM, ComponentTypes> componentPool;
    std::atomic_bool gameOver{false};

public:
    void runGame() {
        // `auto` overload is the least specialized so `update()` is the default
        static auto process = overload(
            [](           auto& comp) { comp.update(); },
            [](RenderComponent& comp) { comp.render(); }
        );

        while (!gameOver) {
            for_each(componentPool, [](auto& components) {
                std::for_each(begin(components), end(components), process);

                // alternatively, equivalently:
                //for (auto& component : components) {
                //    process(component);
                //}
            });
        }
    }
    void endGame() { gameOver = true; }
};
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fd7088034c3383b)**</kbd>

Now you need to manage `MAX_NUM` and `ComponentTypes`, and also potentially add a new overload to `process` (though you'll get a compiler error if you forget).

Answer (score 0):

You have a well defined interface you want from your objects so we can simply use an interface and multiple inheritance, but your component list cannot be the owning pointer here.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct ComponentInterface {
    virtual void update();
};

struct AIComponent : public ComponentInterface {
    virtual void update() override {
        std::cout << "AIComponent\n";
    }
};

struct GraphicsStuff {};

public RenderComponent : public GraphicsStuff, ComponentInterface {
    virtual void update() override {
        std::cout << "Render\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<ComponentInterface*> components;
    AIComponent ai;
    RenderComponent render;
    components.push_back(&ai);
    components.push_back(&render);
    for (auto&& comp: components) {
        comp->update();
    }
}
```